# Is a free group of finite rank $r>1$ polycyclic by finite?

Tags: abstract-algebra, free-groups

Recall that a group G is called polycyclic-by-finite (or virtually polycyclic) if there exists a normal subgroup of finite index $N$ in $G$ such that $N$ is polycyclic.
I know that a free group of finite rank $r>1$ is not a polycyclic group  because it is not solvable.
 My question is that :
Is a free group of finite rank $r>1$ polycyclic by finite?

Thanks.

Comment: Free groups are not virtually polycyclic (see fundamental groups of affinely flat manifolds).

Comment: @DietrichBurde : Thank you so much,

Answer (score 1):

If $G$ is free of rank finite rank $r>1$ and $N\subseteq G$ is a subgroup of finite index, then $N$ is free of finite rank $\geq r$.  A cute way to prove this is using covering spaces: let $X$ be a wedge of $r$ circles.  Then $\pi_1(X)\cong G$, and there is a covering space $p:Y\to X$ such that $\pi_1(Y)\cong N$ (with the induced map on $\pi_1$ being the inclusion map $N\to G$).  Since $N$ has finite index, $p$ is finite-sheeted, so $Y$ is a finite graph and $\pi_1(Y)$ is free of finite rank, say $s$.  Moreover, if $p$ is $n$-sheeted, then $\chi(Y)=n\chi(X)$.  Since $\chi(X)=1-r$ and $\chi(Y)=1-s$, this means $1-s=n(1-r)$ or $s=nr-n+1$.  Since $r>1$ and $n\geq 1$, we conclude that $s\geq r$.

So, the result you mentioned applies to $N$, and such a subgroup $N$ cannot be polycyclic.